# svproc and amsthm incompatibility

Tags: amsthm, incompatibility

I am writing a paper that requires the document class [svproc](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/publish-a-book/step-by-step-conference-proceedings)

When running a MWE

```
\documentclass{styles/svproc}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
Hello   
\end{document}
```

I get the following error: `Command \proof already defined.`

Any ideas on how to sort this compatibility issue?

Comment: `svproc` uses its own methods for defining theorem-like environments and `proof`. If you're required to use the class, don't load `amsthm`.